# Kali Linux VM stuck on installation

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, installation, kali-linux

I am trying to set up Kali Linux on VirtualBox but it is stuck in the 'Select and Install Software' step. The progress bar shows that it is nearly completed, but it has been stuck on 'Unpacking libxcb1-dev (amd64)' for what would have to be nearly 40 mins now. I have enough space on my computer for the installation and my both cpu and memory usage are fine. VirtualBox and the .iso file are up to date and my internet connection is also ok so I am not sure what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Find another distro. Kali is for advanced security researchers only & is not named after the Hindu god. Anything that Kali can provide can quite easily be available in every other distro. I really wish Kali would die a death, it's caused far more issues than it's worth.